# How to Add Display text and Click Event to a Dynamic Prefab Object created on Runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to Add Display text and Click Event to a Dynamic Prefab Object created on Runtime in Unity.

This is my c# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateMarkerPin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]

    public Vector3 TargetPosition = new Vector3(0.09f, 0.5f, 1.1f);
    // Instead of using Resources simply reference the 
    // created Prefab here
    public GameObject gameObjectPinPrefab;

    [Header("Outputs")]
    public GameObject gameObjectPinInstantiate;

    private void Start()
    {
        TargetPosition = new Vector3(0.09f, 0.5f, 1.1f);

        gameObjectPinPrefab = (GameObject)Resources.Load("gameObjectPinPrefab");
       //The object the script is attached to
        GameObject world = this.gameObject;
        //Instantiate the prefab
        gameObjectPinInstantiate = Instantiate(gameObjectPinPrefab, TargetPosition, Quaternion.identity, world.transform);


        Debug.Log("InstantiateMarkerPin class : Marker  Location 2 :X, Y, Z : " + gameObjectPinInstantiate.transform.position);
    }

}
```

[Globe with pin object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJil4.png)

In the Pin object i want to add a label and a click event

Comment: Also as a new question this is unfortunately still to broad / off-topic as searching for a tutorial/tool. there are many options of how to display text and get user clicks in Unity .. like said: Either go for a Canvas with `Image`, `Text` and a `Button` or go on using the `SpriteRenderer` a `TextMesh` and create your own button using e.g. the `IPointerClickHandler` interface.. make all of it part of the prefab so you don't have to take care of it in code

Comment: And you should probably remove my comments from the code ^^

Answer (score 0):

To add a Component to an object in code you can do something like:

```
Text t = gameObject.AddComponent<Text>();
t.text = "Whatever";
```

Also the label will noot render unless the object you are adding it is a child of a Canvas. You may want to get a reference to your canvas in the code and use `gameObject.transform.parent = \\canvas object`

Regarding the onclick I would just add a button to this object from the code:

```
Button b = gameObject.AddComponent<Button>();
b.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);
```

From here you just need to define a function elsewhere named OnClick, or whatever you choose to call it, that handles the click event. You may also want to make your button invisible and do whatever else seems necessary.

Comment: I tried the code but not working do I need to add this code before Instantiate() or after ?The code modified is here :https://www.codepile.net/pile/1qYWllXe

Comment: I don't see the modified code at that link. What I provided was not the exact code just a basic skeleton. You need to instantiate the object and save that game object in a variable. Then you need to call AddComponent<> etc on the variable you created for that marker. @JerryAbraham